# Ant Build Test Target

Tags: testing, ant, junit, build

I'm working with ant for the first time, read lots of tutorials and examples, and still cant make this works. Every target works, but with test im getting 
"Test TestMaze failed (crashed)."
I've tried to change lot of things (using lot of examples), still nothing. Can anyone tell me where is the problem please? Thanks a lot.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<project name="Maze" default="default" basedir=".">


  <property name="src.dir" location="src" />
  <property name="build.dir" location="build" />
  <property name="dist.dir" location="dest-server" />
  <property name="test.dir" location="test" />
  <property name="test.report.dir" location="testreport" />


  <target name="clean">
    <delete dir="${build.dir}" />
    <delete dir="${dist.dir}" />
    <delete dir="${test.report.dir}" />
  </target>

  <path id="junit.class.path">
    <pathelement location="lib/junit-4.10.jar" />
    <pathelement location="${build.dir}" />
  </path>


  <target name="compile" depends="clean">
        <mkdir dir="${build.dir}" />
        <mkdir dir="${dist.dir}" />
    <javac srcdir="${src.dir}" destdir="${build.dir}" />
    <javac srcdir="${test.dir}" destdir="${build.dir}">
     <classpath refid="junit.class.path" />
    </javac>
    <jar destfile="${dist.dir}\Maze.jar" basedir="${build.dir}">
       <manifest>
           <attribute name="Main-Class" value="maze.tape.Commands" />
       </manifest>
    </jar>

  </target>

  <target name="test" depends="compile">
    <junit printsummary="on" fork="true" haltonfailure="yes">
        <classpath refid="junit.class.path" />
        <formatter type="xml" />
        <batchtest todir="${test.report.dir}">
            <fileset dir="${test.dir}">
                <include name="**/*Test*.java" />
            </fileset>
        </batchtest>
    </junit>
  </target>

  <target name="run" depends="compile">
    <java jar="dest-server/Maze.jar" fork="true"/>
  </target>

</project>
```

Comment: I know it doesn't solve your immediate problem, but you've got your build script's default target set to 'default', and there is no target named 'default' defined in your script.  You probably want to change `default="default"` to something like `default="run"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your test target is generating an xml file because you are using:

```
<formatter type="xml" />
```

when the attribute **usefile** is not used, the default value will be set and in this case, the value is "**true**".

You can set the attribute to false and the output will be displayed in the console.